# obtener el actor más premiado

Tags: java

El problema que estoy teniendo es que no se como diseñar el siguiente método para obtener lo esperado:

```
public String getActorMasPremiado(String[] vecActores) throws ActorNoExiste{}
```

Tiene que Indicar de la lista pasada el actor con mayor premiaciones obtenidas   (mirando todas las categorías). Si llega a encontrar mas de un actor, se    debe seleccionar uno. El vector vecActores tiene   los número  de  pasaporte   de  los actores.

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class SistemaProductora{

        static ArrayList<Actor> lista = new ArrayList<Actor>();

        public static void crearActor(String numeroPasaporte, String nombreCompleto)throws ActorYaExiste, InformacionInvalida{

            for(int x=0;x<lista.size();x++) {
                    if(lista.get(x).getNumeroPasaporte().equals(numeroPasaporte)){
                            throw new ActorYaExiste("este actor ya fue registrado ");
                    }
            }
            if(numeroPasaporte.equals(null)||nombreCompleto.equals(null)){
                throw new InformacionInvalida("informacion invalida");
            }
            Actor a=new Actor(nombreCompleto,numeroPasaporte);
            lista.add(a);
        }

        public static void nominarActor(String numeroPasaporte, boolean[]vecNominaciones)throws ActorNoExiste, InformacionInvalida{

            for(int x=0;x<lista.size();x++) {
                    if(!lista.get(x).getNumeroPasaporte().equals(numeroPasaporte)){
                            throw new ActorNoExiste("este actor no existe ");
                    }
            }   
            if(numeroPasaporte.equals(null)||vecNominaciones.equals(null)){
                throw new InformacionInvalida("info invalida");
            }
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                if(vecNominaciones[i]=true){
                    Actor.nominaciones[i]++;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void premiarActor(String numeroPasaporte, boolean[]vecPremiaciones)throws ActorNoExiste, InformacionInvalida{
            for(int x=0;x<lista.size();x++) {
                    if(!lista.get(x).getNumeroPasaporte().equals(numeroPasaporte)){
                            throw new ActorNoExiste("este actor no existe ");
                    }
            }   
            if(numeroPasaporte.equals(null)||vecPremiaciones.equals(null)){
                throw new InformacionInvalida("info invalida");
            }
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                if(vecPremiaciones[i]=true){
                    Actor.premiaciones[i]++;
                }
            }
        }

        /*public static String getActorMasPremiado(String[] vecActores) throws ActorNoExiste{
            int max=0;
            int[] prem=new int [4];
            String nom=null;
            for(int x=0;x<lista.size();x++){
                for(int i=0;i<vecActores.length;i++){
                    if(lista.get(x).getNumeroPasaporte().equals(vecActores[i])){
                        throw new ActorNoExiste(" no existe");
                        prem=lista.get(x).getPremiaciones();
                        nom=lista.get(x).getNombreCompleto();
                        if(prem[i]>max){
                            max=prem[i];
                        }
                    }

                }
            }                


            return nom;

        }
        */




        public static void main(String []args){
            try{
            try{
            crearActor("w678xebu","pepe risas");
            }catch(ActorYaExiste e){
                System.out.println("Error debido a: "+e.getMessage());
            }}catch(InformacionInvalida e){
                System.out.println("Error debido a: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }


    }



    public class Actor{


    private String nombreCompleto;
    private String numeroPasaporte;
    private boolean[] vecNominaciones=new boolean[4];
    public static int[] nominaciones=new int[4];
    public static int[] premiaciones=new int[4];
    private String []vecActores=new String[10];

    //Constructor
    public Actor(String nombreCompleto,String numeroPasaporte,boolean[]vecNominaciones,int[]premiaciones){
        this.nombreCompleto=nombreCompleto;
        this.numeroPasaporte=numeroPasaporte;
        this.vecNominaciones=vecNominaciones;
        this.premiaciones=premiaciones;     
    }

    public Actor(String nombreCompleto,String numeroPasaporte){
        this.nombreCompleto=nombreCompleto;
        this.numeroPasaporte=numeroPasaporte;
    }

    //******SET*********
    public void setNombreCompleto(String nombreCompleto){
        this.nombreCompleto=nombreCompleto;
    }
    public void setNumeroPasaporte(String numeroPasaporte){
        this.numeroPasaporte=numeroPasaporte;
    }
    public void setVecNominaciones(boolean[] vecNominaciones){
        this.vecNominaciones=vecNominaciones;
    }
    public void setVecActores(String[] vecActores){
        this.vecActores=vecActores;
    }
    public void setPremiaciones(int[] premiaciones){
        this.premiaciones=premiaciones;
    }
    public void setNominaciones(int[] nominaciones){
        this.nominaciones=nominaciones;
    }
    //*********GET**********
    public String getNombreCompleto(){
        return nombreCompleto;
    }
    public String getNumeroPasaporte(){
        return numeroPasaporte;
    }
    public boolean[] getVecNominaciones(){
        return vecNominaciones;
    }
    public int[] getPremiaciones(){
        return premiaciones;
    }
    public String[] getVecActores(){
        return vecActores;
    }
    public int[] getNominaciones(int[] nominaciones){
        this.nominaciones=nominaciones;
    }
}
```

Comment: La funcion nominaractor funciona? si tenes mas de un actor y pedis otro que no sea el primero, funciona? la funcion premiaractor sufre el mismo problema... y para la funcion que falta, no estas complicando todo? digo, no es recorrer la lista, y guardar en algun lado la cuenta por pasaporte? y despues agarrar de ese lado el que tenga mas?

Comment: Hola gbianchi , si ambas funciones tanto nominActor como premiarActor funcionan, no entiendo como decis que se puede facilitar el camino ,para la funcion que falta me pasan un vector con los pasaportes de los actores y yo tengo que primero verificar si el actor existe , de lo contrario lanzar una exception , luego si existe tengo que ver cual de todos los de la lista tiene el mayor numero de premiaciones sin importar cual categoria(hay 4 categorias por ese motivo el vector)y tiene que devolver el nombre del actor el cual tiene mas premiaciones

Comment: en nominar actor y premiar actor, el if esta mal. esta devolviendo error si el pasaporte que te pasan figura en la lista de actores. Eso pasa porque lo copiaste de crearactor, y en ese caso el if esta bien. fijate eso. la otra funcion es simple, por cada actor de la lista que te pasan lo buscas, contas los premios y te quedas con ese actor, hasta que otro tenga mas premios.

Comment: Tenes razón no me había dado cuenta del if , si lo copie y pensé que había cambiado todos los detalles pero ese se me paso,ya voy a editar la pregunta para corregirlo.Claro entiendo tu idea pero no se como ponerla en código

Comment: hay mas problemas en tu codigo. no lo podes resolver, porque hay cosas que no estan del todo bien. Por ejemplo el vector premiaciones, que tiene? vos lo declaraste como un vector de 4 posiciones, y que contiene? ya se que contiene enteros.. pero que enteros? y para que contiene 4 enteros? esto te lo pasaron asi en clase o lo armaste vos? yendo a la base de tu problema, si te dijera que me dijeras cuantos premios gano un actor, como lo harias? empeza pensando ese problema...

Comment: Es muy pero muy importante, que cuando copies codigo entiendas que estas copiando. Por ejemplo, podrias explicar en tu codigo, linea por linea, que trataste de hacer en el metodo getactormaspremiado?

Comment: tus funciones siguen estando mal. ponerle ! adelante no soluciona el problema. si te pasan el pasaporte del segundo actor en una lista de dos, el primero ya tiraria error.

Comment: y porque actores tiene un vector de actores adentro? me parece que hay que solucionar muchas cosas..

Comment: ven al [chat], y abrimos una sala, y vamos solucionando los problemas de tu codigo uno a uno.

Comment: Dale ya voy a una sala

Answer (score 1):

Además de lo que te han señalado encontré un error en el código del método que estas mostrando. Estas guardando en nombre del actor dentro del if en el que compruebas si el actor existe y no el que tomas el actor mas premiado por ello cada ves que iteras vas cambiando el valor de nom independientemente de si es el mas premiado o no,puede que lo encuentres y como sigues comprobando actores el nombre no te queda registrado.

```
    public static String getActorMasPremiado(String[] vecActores) throws ActorNoExiste{
    int max=0;
    int[] prem=new int [4];
    String nom=null;
    for(int x=0;x<=lista.size();x++){
        for(int i=0;i<vecActores.length-1;i++){
            if(lista.get(x).getNumeroPasaporte().equals(vecActores[i])){
                throw new ActorNoExiste(" no existe");
                prem=lista.get(x).getPremiaciones();
                if(prem[i]>max){
                    max=prem[i];
                    nom=lista.get(x).getNombreCompleto();
                }
            }

        }
    }  
    return nom;

}
```

Espero te sirva de algo.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la ayuda, al probarlo me tira este error

Comment: javac SistemaProductora.java
SistemaProductora.java:61: error: unreachable statement
                prem=lista.get(x).getPremiaciones();
                ^

Comment: Buenas tardes, ese errror indica que parte del codigo no se va a ejecutar. Ya lo he modificado, el ciclo que recorre el array estaba solo hasta .length y lo he cambiado por .length-1. Prueba ahora.

Comment: Ya lo probe Yoelvis pero sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: lo volvi a editar prueba de nuevo